# Residue theorem change of variables

Tags: complex-analysis

Is there is a change of variables formula for residues?
I recently saw a computation of the residue of $f(z)=e^{7z}/(1-e^{-z})^{8}$ "by change of variable $w=1-e^{-z}$". Can someone state the principle behind this rigorously?

Comment: $Res(f(z),a) = \frac{1}{2i\pi}\int_{|z-a|=\epsilon} f(z)dz$ where $\epsilon$ is small enough such that $f(z)$ is holomorphic on $0 < |z-a| < \epsilon$. So it reduces to the change of variable formula for contour integrals : $\int_\gamma g(z)dz= \int_{h^{-1}(\gamma)} g(h(s))h'(s)ds$ where $h(s)$ is [biholomorphic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biholomorphism) on the neigborhood of $\gamma$

Comment: @user1952009 very instructive comment! I didn't know about change of variables for contour integrals.

Answer (score 2):

Here's the simplest case.  Suppose $f$ has a simple pole at $a$.  Thus

$$ \text{Res}(f, a) = \lim_{z \to a} (z-a) f(z)$$

Now suppose $g$ is analytic in a neighbourhood of $b$ with $g(b) = a$ and $g'(b) \ne 0$.
Then

$$ \eqalign{ \text{Res}(f \circ g, b) &= \lim_{w \to b} (w-b) f(g(w)) \cr
&= \lim_{w  \to b} \dfrac{w-b}{g(w)-a} (g(w)-a) f(g(w))\cr
&= \lim_{w  \to b} \dfrac{w-b}{g(w)-a} \lim_{z \to a} (z-a) f(z)\cr
&= \frac{\text{Res}(f, a)}{g'(b)}}$$

If the pole is not simple or $g(w)-a$ has a higher-order zero at $b$, you need to consider more terms in the Laurent series and it gets a lot more complicated.

Comment: thanks, this is known to me, but how can one apply this to work out the residue in my particular example?

Comment: I don't know.  This is a pole of order $8$.